# Openapi generator: Add import class to generated model

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi-generator

I am using Openapi generator(5.4.0), with spring (generator name) and gradle, I am trying to add an import to a generated model.

For the particular field in the api spec, I  have added:

```
 x-field-extra-annotation: "@com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat ...."
```

This works, however I dont want to fully qualify it, and have the com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat import added.

I tried adding typeMappings to genratedCode task, but that doesn't work.

```
importMappings = [
            'JsonFormat'    : 'com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat'
    ]
```

Update:
I can add model.mustache template to project, and add the import. ie

```
{{#useBeanValidation}}
...
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat;
...
{{/useBeanValidation}}
```

Any ideas? Better ways.
Thanks.

Comment: Are you looking for OOTB solution (it seems that openapi generator does not support what you want, if forget about an "option" to put stuff into `x-class-extra-annotation`) or asking how improve `mustache` template?

Answer (score 0):

There is no production-ready solution (yet!)
If you are not starving for this feature, wait for acceptance of related issue and PR to one of the nearest releases.
https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/issues/13938
It will allow required customizations using
x-spring-constraint: @MyAnnotation(value = 1, message = "nice") (or x-java-constraint) extension with configOption
customValidationAnnotationsPackages="my.custom.package.MyAnnotaion;my.other.package.*"

Else, refer to https://bartko-mat.medium.com/openapi-generator-to-spring-boot-with-custom-java-validations-623381df9215 as tutorial for handmade solution